# Flask-Redis python: redis.exceptions.ResponseError: DB index is out of range

Tags: python, redis, flask-restful

I am using flask-Redis and while using a connection like  'redis://:password@localhost:6379/3' getting an error:  redis.exceptions.ResponseError: DB index is out of range.
and while using a connection like  'redis://:localhost:6379/3' it's working fine. I can't figure out how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to replace the `3` at the end of your connection string with a `0` The formatted string should look like this

```
redis://{username}:{password}@localhost:6379/0
```

`DB index is out of range` means that the channel index at the end of your connection string (`3`) exceeds the maximum value for your installation. Usually there are 16 channels, so without further information it is unclear what this maximum value might be for your particular version. However, assuming Redis is properly installed, you can be assured that the value of `0` will be within the correct index range. You can easily verify your installation using the `redis-cli` tool

```sh
$ redis-cli -n 0 -h localhost -c 'PING'
PONG
```

Unless you have a very compelling reason to do otherwise, you should stick to using the default channel value of `0`. You can read more about this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/redis-db/vS5wX8X4Cjg/8ounBXitG4sJ) from the author of Redis himself.

If you have not explicitly configured Redis to require a password, then no value need be supplied. Same for the username, by default Redis will not have a value set so both of these can be omitted, which is why when you say the second version of the connection string works, it does.